# I can't fit a picture in pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet

I am trying to load a HD picture (1280x720) into `pyglet` window. I setup the same window size as the image has, but the output is still cropped. My screen resolution is 1920x1080 if it matters, but I won't have the window on fullscreen either.

image:
[image]

output in `pyglet` app:

[image]

My code:

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=1280, height=720)
image = pyglet.image.load('pic.jpg')
@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    image.blit(0,0)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture you linked is `https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvdHj.jpg` which is 1920x1080. I think you may the dimensions mixed up?

Comment: that is so weird. i would swear i tried both scenario, but obviously I did not, cause it works as you pointed out.

Comment: No worries. Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes on things.